# Поменять класс у Checkbox'a

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сделал, чтобы при нажатии на checkbox к элементу списка добавлялся класс "checked". Но почему-то не работает.

И как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на "Выделить все" выделялось все?

```js
$('#list .toggle').on('click', 'input.checkbox', function() {
  $('li').toggleClass('checked')
});
```

```css
#toggle-all {
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
}

#toggle-all::before {
  content: "❯";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #49f;
  padding: 10px 27px;
}

#list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#list li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid #49f;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

#list li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #49f;
}

#list li .toggle {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#list li .toggle:checked:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#bddad5" stroke-width="3"/><path fill="#5dc2af" d="M72 25L42 71 27 56l-4 4 20 20 34-52z"/></svg>');
}

#list li .toggle:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#ededed" stroke-width="3"/></svg>')
}

#list li label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 15px 60px 15px 15px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.2;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox"> Выделить все
</p>
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <div class="task">
      <label> <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">First</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="task">
      <label> <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">Second</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="task">
      <label> <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">Third</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[<sub>Пример на jsfiddle</sub>](https://jsfiddle.net/9qkovqnj/1/)

Comment: Селектор `input.checkbox` не будет работать, потому что нет ни одного инпута с классом `checkbox`

Comment: А в сниппете на jsfiddle вы просто забыли jQuery подключить

Comment: даже если убрать класс checkbox, все равно не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $toggle = $('#list .toggle');

$toggle.on('change', function() {
  var $toggle_checked = $('#list .toggle:checked');

  $(this).parents('li').toggleClass('checked');
  if( $toggle_checked.length == $toggle.length ){
    $('#toggle-all').prop('checked', true);
  }else{
    $('#toggle-all').prop('checked', false);
  };
});

$('#toggle-all').on('change', function() {
  var $li = $('#list li'),
      $toggle_checked = $('#list .toggle:checked');
      
  if( $toggle_checked.length == $toggle.length ){
    $toggle.prop('checked', false);
    $li.removeClass('checked');
  }else{
    $toggle.prop('checked', true);
    $li.addClass('checked');
  };
});
```

```css
#toggle-all {
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

#toggle-all::before {
  content: "❯";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #49f;
  padding: 10px 27px;
}

#toggle-all:checked {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#list li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid #49f;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

#list li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #49f;
}

#list li .toggle {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
}

#list li .toggle:checked:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#bddad5" stroke-width="3"/><path fill="#5dc2af" d="M72 25L42 71 27 56l-4 4 20 20 34-52z"/></svg>');
}

#list li .toggle:after {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#ededed" stroke-width="3"/></svg>')
}

#list li label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-break: break-all;
  padding: 15px 60px 15px 15px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.2;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <input id="toggle-all" type="checkbox"> Выделить все
</p>
<ul id="list">
  <li>
    <div class="task">
      <label> <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">First</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="task">
      <label> <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">Second</label>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="task">
      <label> <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">Third</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Когда поменял на чекбоксе "Выделить все" addClass на toggleClass, то при втором нажатии на этот чекбокс, галочки с других чекбоксов не убираются

Comment: @Imp3l, вы сказали установить на все.. Про убрать слова не было

Comment: невнятное ТЗ было, моя ошибка :)

Comment: @Imp3l, добавил

Comment: Pull request: `input:focus{outline: none;}`, а то аж кровь из глаз.

Comment: @Other, CSS не мой :)

Comment: @Other посоветуйте, как лучше сделать :)

Comment: @Yuri, ответ же Ваш.

Comment: @Imp3l, да вроде всё работает, что советовать-то?

Comment: @Other я про `input:focus{outline: none;}`

Comment: @Imp3l, просто добавьте к стилям - уйдёт безобразная синяя (в хроме) обводка при клике.

Comment: @Other она есть в моем проекте :) Давно уже в свой css не заглядывал, все со скриптами вожусь

Comment: @Other, не увидел стиля `input:focus{outline: none;}` у себя в CSS. Но подправил скрипт